# Deploying Strapi V4 Serverless via Docker ECR container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, serverless, strapi

I've been following [this](https://blog.vikfand.com/posts/serverless-strapi-4-guide/) blog post:

But with a slight twist as following the above hits the 250mb limit AWS Lambda limit (no idea how the original author managed to do without).

So my alternative was to try using ECR/Docker to deploy instead.

my docker image is building and deploying to serverless fine, however when I try to access the application on a route i.e. `/dev/api/users` my serverless log keeps throwing this error:

```
INFO    Cold starting Strapi
/bin/sh: hostname: command not found
[2022-10-03 17:43:49.672] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2022-10-03 17:43:49.674] error: The public folder (/var/task/public) doesn't exist or is not accessible. Please make sure it exists.
Error: The public folder (/var/task/public) doesn't exist or is not accessible. Please make sure it exists.
at module.exports (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/bootstrap.js:29:11)
at async Strapi.register (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:380:5)
at async Strapi.load (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:474:5)
at async startStrapi (/var/task/app.js:16:7)
at async Runtime.module.exports.strapiHandler [as handler] (/var/task/app.js:36:5)
```

My `Dockerfile` image:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:16
WORKDIR /var/task
RUN npm i python3
COPY src /var/task
COPY build /var/task
COPY config /var/task
COPY database /var/task
COPY public /var/task
COPY package*.json /var/task
COPY .env.example /var/task
RUN npm install
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/task
CMD [ "app.strapiHandler" ]
```

Handler function in `app.js`

```
module.exports.strapiHandler = async (event, context) => {
  let workingDir = process.cwd();
  if (process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT && process.env.IS_OFFLINE !== "true") {
    workingDir = process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT;
  }
  if (!global.strapi) {
    console.info("Cold starting Strapi");
    Strapi({ dir: workingDir });
  }
  if (!global.strapi.isLoaded) {
    await startStrapi(global.strapi);
  }
  const handler = serverless(global.strapi.server.app);
  return handler(event, context);
};
```

I am copying my public directory to the `/var/task` folder. But the error keeps persisting. Feel like I've hit a wall and it's business critical I get this solved.

Any insight would be appreciated.

NOTE: the `chmod -R 777` is temporary whilst I try and fix this. Figured it may have been a permission issue.

EDIT:

Managed to solve the above. If anyone wants to know how please reach out happy to help anyone on a similar path with Serverless and headless CMS.

New issue:

```
error: Forbidden access
ForbiddenError: Forbidden access
at Object.verify (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/strategies/users-permissions.js:94:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async /var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:31:5
at async serve (/var/task/node_modules/koa-static/index.js:59:5)
at async returnBodyMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:52:18)
at async policiesMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/policy.js:24:5)
at async /var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/middlewares/body.js:58:9
at async /var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/middlewares/logger.js:25:5
at async /var/task/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/middlewares/powered-by.js:16:5
at async cors (/var/task/node_modules/@koa/cors/index.js:61:32)
```

I'm a super user so not letting me access my own `/api/users` route.

EDIT 2:

Also managed to solve the Forbidden access issue.
My latest issue is that when I go to content-builder-plugin in the admin is saying that it needs autoReload to be enabled. Anyone know how to config so that this is enabled?

Comment: Hi - Nothing useful to contribute I'm afraid, but I'm in exactly the same position (can't get strapi deployed via lambda due to size limit), and am trying the same thing (deploying via lambda container) and have found your post after googling "lambda container strapi". Anything you can share - dockerfile, serverless.yml, etc - would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: @Wintermute no worries dude. Shoot me an email - gkurl@hotmail.co.uk. Have resolved most of my issues here I think.

Comment: Can you share here how you solved the Forbidden access issue please?

Comment: @Sam I've posted an answer with my Dockerfile that should help you guys out - apologies for the late response.

Comment: @Wintermute please see my answer for example dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

Forbidden access issue was solved by having the following Dockerfile structure - I figured out in the end the directories need to be mapped explicitly to their Docker container folders for the admin to work properly - here is my Dockerfile example - I also had to add a few npm install commands in order to get it running.

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:16
WORKDIR /var/task
RUN npm i python3
COPY src /var/task/src
COPY build /var/task/build
COPY config /var/task/config
COPY database /var/task/database
COPY public /var/task/public
COPY package*.json /var/task
COPY .env.example /var/task
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/task
CMD [ "/var/task/src/app.strapiHandler" ]
```

Any questions let me know! There are also some serverless.yml tweaks and strapi security config required in order to get images and media uploading/working properly.